# How can I bind a list to a parameter in a custom query in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using this SQL for performance reasons:

```
 sql_tmpl = """delete from Data where id_data in (:iddata) """
 params = {
                    'iddata':[1, 2,3 4],
                    }

 # 'session' is a session object from SQLAlchemy
 self.session.execute(text(sql_tmpl), params)
```

However, I got an exception:

```
NotSupportedError: (NotSupportedError) ('Python type list not supported.  param=1', 'HY097')
```

Is there a workaround that can allow me to bind a list to the parameter of the 'in' clause?

Comment: The values passed to an IN are still discrete, rendered values in SQL, so the SQL statement itself must still be formed to include a separate bound parameter.   If you are using literal SQL you need to do a string concatenation of ":iddata1, :iddata2, .." etc.  Gary's answer below is the correct one.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`psycopg2` now supports [type adaptation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#python-types-adaptation), which allows, among other things, the ability to pass a list into a single parameterized value in the query. This also works in SQLAlchemy, at the very least for raw-SQL-esque queries to a PostgreSQL database (I don't have access to other database types, so I don't know if `sqlalchemy` will respect this convention for other databases, but my inclination<sup>citation needed</sup> is that it will work).

```
some_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
query = "SELECT * FROM my_table t WHERE t.id = ANY(:ids);"
conn.execute(sqlalchemy.text(query), ids=some_ids)
## runs just fine
```

I found that without the wrapper call to `sqlalchemy.text`, it gave a `ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ":"`.

Comment: I have below error using above code

           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    react_data = rc_db.execute(react_query, ids=posts_data_list).all()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Session.execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ids'

Answer (score 74):

A new approach to this problem that works for any database (not just relying on psycopg2's type adaptation) uses expanding bind parameters:

```py
sql_tmpl = """delete from Data where id_data in :iddata"""
params = { 'iddata': [1, 2, 3, 4], }
# session is a session object from sqlalchemy
t = text(sql_tmpl)
t = t.bindparams(bindparam('iddata', expanding=True))
self.session.execute(t, params)
```

Comment: With `pymysql` and SQLAlchemy 1.2 this was not needed. The `expanding` feature appears to be related to statement caching. More details here: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/3953

Comment: @jnylen That's because pymysql supports list adaptation. Expanding bindparams is handy for more than just baked (cached) queries, since not all DB-API drivers support list adaptation, in which case you'd have to manually form and format the required placeholders into a query. It's also significantly faster in certain queries, such as passing a huge list to `in_()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57829682/new-override-sqlalchemy-operator-compiler-output

Comment: to help anyone this imports are needed:
from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy import bindparam

Comment: Why do we have to include ¡¡

Comment: Why do we have to include `params` in this line `self.session.execute(t, params)`? Didn't we already bind them in the previous line? What does this line do then? `t = t.bindparams(bindparam('iddata', expanding=True))`

Comment: @MadPhysicist `params` has the actual parameter value that needs to be added to the query. `bindparam('iddata', expanding=True)` only flags the key `iddata` as 'to-be-expanded'.

Comment: Using `bindparams` allowed me to work around mixed behavior from MySQL and Snowflake SqlAlchemy drivers. MySQL wanted no parens around the `:list_param` in the query, whereas Snowflake needed parens ( https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy/issues/326 ).

Comment: how would you bind and pass mutliple params in this case? are we gonna have to write code to iterate a dictionary of params and values in such cases?

Answer (score 14):

Use a tuple instead of a list and you don't need parentheses around the parameter in the query:

```
sql_tmpl = "delete from Data where id_data in :iddata"
params = {  
   'iddata':(1, 2, 3, 4),
}
self.session.execute(text(sql_tmpl), params)
```

Answer (score 11):

Try it without the parentheses around, `:iddata`. That has been working for me.

```
sql_tmpl = """delete from Data where id_data in :iddata """
```

Comment: Works fine, but the parameter must be a tuple. Won't work with a list.

Comment: Depends on DB-API driver in use.

Comment: Does not work for SQL Server

Answer (score 4):

Adding to [dwanderson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190392/how-can-i-bind-a-list-to-a-parameter-in-a-custom-query-in-sqlalchemy/39414254#39414254): using SQLAlchemy, you can use the [func](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func) method to add the "any" function to a query. This works for me using SQLAlchemy 1.0.9 and a PostgreSQL database.

Generic example:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

# some list
id_list = [1, 2, 3]

# assuming you have created a session
query = session.query(Table.user_name, Table.user_id).\
    filter(Table.user_id == func.any(id_list))

# one way of running the query
query.all()
```

You can verify that the list is passed as a single parameter (as opposed to a parameter per object in the list).

```
print(query.statement)
```

> SELECT user_id, user_name
> FROM table
> WHERE table.user_id = any(:any_1)

Answer (score 3):

Jason Damiani's answer works when you are performing an execution. But if you want to get the stringified form of the text clause, you need to use `bindparam()` and apply `expanding=True`.

Example:

```py
mylist = [1,2,3]
query = text("mycolumn IN :arr")
  .bindparams(bindparam(key="arr", value=mylist, expanding=True))
  .compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})
print(query)
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, none of the SQL engines allow passing in an array parameter. The way that SQLAlchemy handles this is to pass in a parameter for each item in the array.

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.sql import table, column
>>> print(table('Data').delete(column('id_data').in_([5, 6, 7,])))
DELETE FROM "Data" WHERE id_data IN (:id_data_1, :id_data_2, :id_data_3)
```

If you don't use the SQLAlchemy expression constructs, you would need to do this manually.

Comment: I don't know if this was the case when the answer was written, but now `psycopg2` supports a [bunch of coercions, including arrays](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#python-types-adaptation). See for example [Tuples adaptation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#tuples-adaptation). Unfortunately, it seems that SQL Alchemy uses its own logic so that this feature is only available if using psycopg2 directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a where clause using a loop and use ** to break out the list in the query.execute parameters. Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/pawl/555e5eecce77d4de0ada

Comment: Going procedural in SQL? What are the downsides?

Comment: Thank you sir. Thats the only way I made this work for MS SQL 17 Drivers

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft SQL Server, you can use Table Valued Parameters to accomplish the same thing.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE customer_id in (SELECT * FROM @MyTVP)
```

TVP's are currently only supported with [PyTDS](https://python-tds.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), not PyODBC. The `expanding=True` flag [detailed by Jason Damiani](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190392/how-can-i-bind-a-list-to-a-parameter-in-a-custom-query-in-sqlalchemy/56382828#56382828) is probably the best way to do this if you have a newer version of SQLAlchemy. But TVP's will do in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is kinda same solution like @Jason Damiani but as one liner (for me more practical):

```
someQuoteIds = [1, 2, 3]
result = connection.execute(
    text("""
        SELECT * FROM quotes 
        WHERE id IN :ids AND tag = :tag""")
    .bindparams(bindparam("ids", expanding=True), ids=someQuoteIds, tag='Character')
)
```

Comment: how do you deal with multiple keys in a params dictionary?

Answer (score -1):

Using this example from above:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

# some list
id_list = [1, 2, 3]

# assuming you have created a session
query = session.query(Table.user_name, Table.user_id).\
    filter(Table.user_id == func.any(id_list))

# one way of running the query
query.all()
```

I had to make change `func.any`, to `func.all` and then it worked! Good luck

Answer (score -6):

In case you are dealing raw SQL, you can go with this approach:

```
ids = [1000032, 1000048]
sql = 'SELECT CompNo, CompName, CompType FROM Component WHERE DeptID IN %(ids)s' % {"ids": tuple(ids)}
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: This code creates a SQL injection error.