# SQLAlchemy filter in_ operator

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to do a simple filter operation on a query in sqlalchemy, like this:

```
q = session.query(Genotypes).filter(Genotypes.rsid.in_(inall))
```

where

inall is a list of strings
Genotypes is mapped to a table:
    class Genotypes(object):
        pass

```
Genotypes.mapper = mapper(Genotypes, kg_table, properties={'rsid': getattr(kg_table.c, 'rs#')})
```

This seems pretty straightforward to me, but I get the following error when I execute the above query by doing `q.first()`:

> "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) too many SQL
>   variables u'SELECT" followed by a list of the 1M items in the *inall*
>   list. But they aren't supposed to be SQL variables, just a list whose
>   membership is the filtering criteria.

Am I doing the filtering incorrectly?

(the db is sqlite)

Answer (score 26):

If the table where you are getting your `rsid`s from is available in the same database I'd use a [subquery](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.subquery) to pass them into your `Genotypes` query rather than passing the one million entries around in your Python code.

```
sq = session.query(RSID_Source).subquery()
q = session.query(Genotypes).filter(Genotypes.rsid.in_(sq))
```

The issue is that in order to pass that list to SQLite (or any database, really), SQLAlchemy has to pass over each entry for your `in` clause as a variable.  The SQL translates roughly to:

```
-- Not valid SQLite SQL
DECLARE @Param1 TEXT;
SET @Param1 = ?;
DECLARE @Param2 TEXT;
SET @Param2 = ?;
-- snip 999,998 more

SELECT field1, field2, -- etc.
FROM Genotypes G
WHERE G.rsid IN (@Param1, @Param2, /* snip */)
```

Comment: Why doesn't it inline them before making a query? It doesn't make sense for me why the above couldn't be just `IN (values...)` instead of `SET @params = values...; ...; ... IN (@params...)`.

Comment: I've tried sub-queries and have not been able to get them to work. the `.subquery()` at the end seems to make all the difference. thanks

Answer (score 11):

The below workaround worked for me:

```
q = session.query(Genotypes).filter(Genotypes.rsid.in_(inall))
query_as_string = str(q.statement.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))
session.execute(query_as_string).first()
```

This basically forces the query to compile as a string before execution, which bypasses the whole variables issue. Some details on this are available in SQLAlchemy's docs [here](http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/sqlexpressions.html#how-do-i-render-sql-expressions-as-strings-possibly-with-bound-parameters-inlined).

BTW, if you're not using SQLite you can make use of the ANY operator to pass the list object as a single parameter (see my answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190392/how-can-i-bind-a-list-to-a-parameter-in-a-custom-query-in-sqlalchemy/42591722#42591722)).

Comment: Any implications or security otherwise?