# SQLAlchemy and empty IN clause

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I found out that SQLAlchemy translates

```
db.query(...).filter(A.id.in_(ids))
```

into

```
SELECT ...
FROM a
WHERE a.id != a.id
```

if `ids` is empty. That results in sequential scan on `a` table, which is obviously disastrous for performance.

The first question is: why? Why not just `1 = 0` or anything that does not require sequential scan?

The second, more important: is is there a commonly used workaround (other than `if` near every `in_`)?

I guess that `in_` cannot be easily reimplemented to cover all cases without causing that problem, but I cannot be the first to face it and there may be some solution covering simple, common use cases of `in_`.

### EDIT

SQLAlchemy logs a warning every time it happens:

`"The IN-predicate on 'foo.bar' was invoked with an empty sequence. This results in a contradiction, which nonetheless can be expensive to evaluate. Consider alternative strategies for improved performance."`

Comment: Interesting article on the topic: [Handling empty WHERE IN clauses in DBALs](http://romain.dorgueil.net/en/database/2011/01/10/handling-empty-where-in-clauses-in-dbals.html).

Comment: The simple, common use case solution that works for me is the if statement. You probably are (or should) be doing some kind of validation. Just add empty lists to your checks and don't waste the DB overhead.

Comment: @LukasGraf That link no longer works, the article is now [here](https://romain.dorgueil.net/blog/en/database/2011/01/10/handling-empty-where-in-clauses-in-dbals.html)

Answer (score 9):

(This is now mainly of historical interest, as SQLAlchemy fixed this bug long ago).

To answer the OP's question of "why", here is the [FAQ entry](https://docs-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/ko/latest/faq/sqlexpressions.html#why-does-col-in-produce-col-col-why-not-1-0) (which I always find surprisingly difficult to find):

> **Why does `.col.in_([])` produce `col != col`? Why not `1=0`?**
>
> A little introduction to the issue. The `IN` operator in SQL, given a
> list of elements to compare against a column, generally does not
> accept an empty list, that is while it is valid to say:
>
> ```
> column IN (1, 2, 3)
> ```
>
> it’s not valid to say:
>
> ```
> column IN ()
> ```
>
> SQLAlchemy's `Operators.in_()` operator, when given an empty list, produces this expression:
>
> ```
> column != column
> ```
>
> As of version 0.6, it also produces a warning stating
> that a less efficient comparison operation will be rendered. This
> expression is the only one that is both database agnostic and produces
> correct results.
>
> For example, the naive approach of "just evaluate to false, by
> comparing 1=0 or 1!=1", does not handle nulls properly. An expression
> like:
>
> ```
> NOT column != column
> ```
>
> will not return a row when `column IS NULL`, but an expression which does not take the column into account, such as:
>
> ```
> NOT 1=0
> ```
>
> will return a row.

As shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42642288/648162), you may be able to use the ANY function to avoid this, since it's syntactically valid even for an empty list (but not supported on SQLite apparently). It's probably faster for large lists too, since it does less string mangling to build the query.

The performance issue with the `in_` operator has [recently been fixed](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/commit/f3b6f4f8da5223fae0a1dd948d4266b2e49e317c) and the fix will probably be in SQLAlchemy 1.2.0.

Comment: New FAQ link https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/faq/sqlexpressions.html#why-does-col-in-produce-col-col-why-not-1-0

Answer (score 8):

I'm using:

```
if len(ids) > 0:
    db.query(...).where(A.id.in_(ids))
else:
    db.query(...).where(False)
```

I tried a `.limit(0)` instead of the `.where(false)` without success.  There is some behind-the-scenes difference in the empty querysets that broke other stuff down the pipeline.  This workaround, while could be faster, at least avoids your mentioned warning.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware what you are asking for:

- Only if the value of `A.id` is *comparable* any comparison can actually succeed. The non-existing value is not comparable to anything, **all** comparisons will result in a non-existing value which in turn is evaluated as *False*. That is, if `A.ID` is `NULL` then `A.ID == anything` is *False* and `A.ID != anything` is also *False*: `A.ID == A.ID || A.ID != A.ID` is *False* if `A.ID` is `NULL`.
- The `IN`-clause with an empty sequence asks if the value is part of the empty list. The non-existing value is part of no list, not even the empty one.
- Hence what you are asking for is some variation of `IS NOT NULL` and **something that is  part of nothing**. This is a condition that has to be checked for. The non-existing value is not something; only some value that is not `NULL` can **not** be be a member of the empty list...
- As sqlalchemy is clever about the fact that this is probably not the way you want to express this condition, it gives a warning. You should probably drop the `IN`-clause if the sequence is empty.

For a concrete example this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79d9bf/9/0)

For a more philosophical approach see [What is the nature of void](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/5)

Answer (score 3):

When I ran into this, it was because I was using an Enum type for one of my database table columns. When I changed it to a String, the problem went away. That's not a real solution, since I would have preferred an Enum, but it did avoid the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The highest sorted answer is no longer correct. As of SQL Alchemy 1.2 this behavior is configurable but defaults to turning these expressions in `1 != 1` instead of the original behavior. This was changed for exactly the performance concern noted in the OP.

> SQLAlchemy in its early days began with this approach as well, but soon it was theorized that the SQL expression column IN () would not evaluate to false if the “column” were NULL; instead, the expression would produce NULL, since “NULL” means “unknown”, and comparisons to NULL in SQL usually produce NULL.
>
> To simulate this result, SQLAlchemy changed from using 1 != 1 to instead use th expression expr != expr for empty “IN” and expr = expr for empty “NOT IN”; that is, instead of using a fixed value we use the actual left-hand side of the expression. If the left-hand side of the expression passed evaluates to NULL, then the comparison overall also gets the NULL result instead of false or true.
>
> Unfortunately, users eventually complained that this expression had a very severe performance impact on some query planners. At that point, a warning was added when an empty IN expression was encountered, favoring that SQLAlchemy continues to be “correct” and urging users to avoid code that generates empty IN predicates in general, since typically they can be safely omitted. However, this is of course burdensome in the case of queries that are built up dynamically from input variables, where an incoming set of values might be empty

- https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_12.html#the-in-not-in-operator-s-empty-collection-behavior-is-now-configurable-default-expression-simplified

Answer (score 1):

use subquery, if `ids` is empty, will (never executed).

example:

```
subquery = db.query(SomeTable.id).filter(...).subquery()

db.query(...).filter(A.id.in_(subquery))
```

into:

```
SELECT ...
FROM a
WHERE a.id IN (SELECT ...)
```