# SQLAlchemy force in_() to use literals

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to force the SQLAlchemy `in_()` operator in a filter to pass *literal* values to the database instead of individual bound variables for each element?

I have to do a (MySQL) query with a potentially-large number of values for an `IN` clause.  (An `IN (SELECT ...)` sub-query is not an option here.)  Something like:

```
query\
    .join(something)\
    .join(somethingelse)\
    .with_entities(somecol, someothercol)\
    .filter(somecol.in_(long_list_of_ids_in_a_list_variable))\
    .order_by(somecol)\
    .all()
```

For this SQLAlchemy sends the following to MySQL:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... JOIN ... 
WHERE id IN (%(id_1)s, %(id_2)s, %(id_3)s, %(id_4)s, %(id_5)s, %(id_6)s,
...
%(id_49)s, %(id_50)s)
ORDER BY ...
{'id_1': 718, 'id_2': 714, 'id_3': 713, 'id_4': 715, 'id_5': 712, 'id_6': 711,
...
'id_49': 657, 'id_50': 656}
```

As the number of `IN` items gets larger this statement gets long and unwieldy (e.g. during debugging at least).  (I don't really think any potential gain here for MySQL query plan re-use by using variables is significant.)

I would like it to send these values just as in-line literals:

```
WHERE id IN (718, 714, 713, 715, 712, 711,
...
657, 656)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this (with `in_()` or some other suitable construct)?  Note that I *only* wish to turn the `IN` segment of the query into literal like this, not all other parts of the query.

[I did look at [SQLAlchemy filter in_ operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158809/sqlalchemy-filter-in-operator), but did not get a suitable answer for mine from there.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`text`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql) construct for your `IN` clause (mindful of sql injection risk):

```
from sqlalchemy_app import Base, Session, engine
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.sql import text


class Something(Base):

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)


class SomethingElse(Base):

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    something_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("something.id"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    s = Session()
    in_clause = text("something.id IN (1, 2, 3)")
    s.query(Something).join(SomethingElse).filter(in_clause).all()
```

Issues this query:

```
2019-08-10 14:23:32,329 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT something.id AS something_id
FROM something INNER JOIN somethingelse ON something.id = somethingelse.something_id
WHERE something.id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about `text()`.

Answer (score 4):

In (at the time of writing this upcoming) version 1.4 you can use an expanding `bindparam` with `literal_execute=True` for just the effect you're after:

```
In [2]: class Foo(Model):
   ...:     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   ...:     data = Column(Integer)

In [3]: metadata.create_all()

In [4]: session.query(Foo).\
   ...:     filter(Foo.data.in_(
   ...:         bindparam('xs', range(10), expanding=True, literal_execute=True))).\
   ...:     all()
2019-09-07 20:35:04,560 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2019-09-07 20:35:04,561 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT foo.id AS foo_id, foo.data AS foo_data 
FROM foo 
WHERE foo.data IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
2019-09-07 20:35:04,561 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
Out[4]: []
```

Comment: I wonder what the 'xs' magic string mean, is it required?

Comment: It is the bind param key, and it is a required argument: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam.params.key

Comment: thanks for your reply. after little try, I noticed it's param name. event without explicitly specify by `bindparam`, sqlalchemy also generate auto name for params.