# SQLAlchemy SQL parameter list substitution with pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to bind a list to a parameter in a raw SQL query in sqlalchemy. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39414254/3128336) suggests a great way to do so with `psycopg2` as below.

```
some_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = ANY(:ids);"
engine.execute(sqlalchemy.sql.text(query), ids=some_ids)
```

However, this does not seems to work for my environment for `SQL Server` with `pyodbc`. Only one `"?"` gets added instead of 4.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) 
('Invalid parameter type. param-index=0 param-type=tuple', 'HY105') 
[SQL: 'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = ANY(?);'] [parameters: ((1, 2, 3, 4),)]
```

Is there any way to make this work? I would like to avoid [manually creating placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/283801/3128336) if possible.

sqlalchemy version=1.0.13, pyodbc version=4.0.16

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for me:

```python
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import table, column, select, literal_column
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://SQLmyDb')
cnxn = engine.connect()
some_ids = [2, 3]
sql = select([literal_column('*')]).where(column('ID').in_(some_ids)).select_from(table('People'))
print(sql)
print('')
params = {":ID_" + str(x+1): some_ids[x] for x in range(len(some_ids))}
rows = cnxn.execute(sql, params).fetchall()
print(rows)
```

which prints the generated SQL statement, followed by the results of the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM "People" 
WHERE "ID" IN (:ID_1, :ID_2)

[(2, 'Anne', 'Elk'), (3, 'Gord', 'Thompson')]
```

Comment: Yes this seems to work for me as well. But the raw SQL query above does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: You could use [`some_ids = [bindparam('id_1'), bindparam('id_2')]`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam) to have explicit control over the parameter names, if wanting to use `executemany()`. In your example case you'd not even need to pass the manually formed `params` to `execute()`, since they're already bound in your statement.

Comment: hmm I see. I guess that is one way. But if possible, I would like to write a raw SQL query and pass a list as a param.