# How to fix data binding issue with SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, data-binding, sqlalchemy

I am using Python 3.6 with Flask. I am trying to connect to Amazon Redshift database using SqlAlchemy. The query has IN operation in the Where clause and the values for it are sent by binding it to the query. For some reason it does not work? It does not error out, but does not fetch any results. If I hard code the values in the query, it works fine.

I have tried a few suggested options but no luck -
    1. binding the values as a list or just as comma separated string
    2. removing the brackets in the query
    3. changing the code to
        stmt = text(file.read())
        stmt = stmt.bindparams(search = ids)
        df = pd.read_sql_query(stmt, connection)

```
    dtv_script.txt
    Select * from tbl1 where id IN (:search)


    def get_dt(id_list):

        engine = create_engine('postgresql://xxxxxxxxxx')

        connection = engine.connect()

        ids = list(id_list.split(","))

        #dtv_script.txt has the sql
        file = open('dtv_script.txt')
        sql = text(file.read())

        df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, connection, params={'search' : ids})

        connection.close()
        return df
```

The ids are posted from a form on the index.html. 
Sample ids = 2011592,2021593,2033591. 
The flask route page captures it in the get_dt() function and returns the dataframe back to the results.html page for display

```
@app.route('/result', methods=['POST']) 
def result(): 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        id_list = request.form.get('ids') 
        df_dt = dofri.get_dt(id_list) 
        return render_template('result.html', **locals()) 
    else: 
        flash('There was some error. Check the logs') 
        return index()
```

Comment: Could you give a small input/output sample to help illustrate your error?

Comment: The ids are posted from a form on the index.html. ids = 2011592,2021593,2033591. The flask route page captures it in the get_dt() function and returns the dataframe back to the results.html page for display. Not sure if this answers your question

Comment: @app.route('/result', methods=['POST'])
def result():
 if request.method == 'POST':

  id_list = request.form.get('ids')
  df_dt = dofri.get_dt(id_list)
  return render_template('result.html', **locals())

 else:
  flash('There was some error. Check the logs')
  return index()

Comment: You can edit your question and add these in for future answerers. The '>' symbol will display them as input/output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I bind a list to a parameter in a custom query in sqlalchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190392/how-can-i-bind-a-list-to-a-parameter-in-a-custom-query-in-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Below is the solution. Make sure to
>
> 1. add - from sqlalchemy import bindparam
> 2. remove -  brackets from the query
> 3. add - expanding=True

```
dtv_script.txt
        Select * from tbl1 where id IN :search

def get_dt(id_list):

    engine = create_engine('postgresql://xxxxxxxxxx')
    connection = engine.connect()

    ids = list(id_list.split(","))

    #dtv_script.txt has the sql
    file = open('dtv_script.txt')


    sql = file.read()


    t = text(sql)
    t = t.bindparams(bindparam('search', expanding=True))
    df = pd.read_sql_query(t, connection, params={'search' : ids })
    connection.close()
    return df
```