# How can I write an update query with IN clause with SQLAlchemy with same efficiency as of plain SQL

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to write the following SQL query efficiently with SQLAlchemy.

```sql
UPDATE item_recs
    SET deleted_at = :deleted_at 
WHERE project_id = :project_id
    AND item_id IN (1602,1603,1604)
```

I have a corrosponding SQLAlchemy model `ItemRec` that has `item_id`, `project_id`, and `deleted_at` as columns. It also has an `id` which is an auto-incremented primary key.

Also, I am running the above query with `session.execute()` method in SQLAlchemy. Right now I am just joining the item_ids in the `IN` clause and concatenating it with the rest of the query. Is there a way to build this `IN` clause with placeholders like `:project_id` instead of using string concatenation?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56382828/5320906)

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
"UPDATE item_recs SET deleted_at = :deleted_at 
WHERE project_id = :project_id
AND item_id IN :item_ids"
```

and then use a tuple as the value for item_ids

```
params = {"item_ids": (1602,1603,1604)}
```

of course, you'll use the params as the argument in the session.execute(sql, params) along with the values for project_id and deleted_at in it as well

Comment: This solution may or may not work, depending on the DBAPI layer being used. For example, even though it may work for PostgreSQL and MySQL, it does not work for Microsoft SQL Server or SQLite.