# PostgreSQL RAW query in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to execute a **raw query** to a PostgreSQL database that works with SqlAlchemy in a Flask project.

I have a class Project and want to query against an array using the IN operator

This is the query that works:

```
db.session.execute( "SELECT * \
                     FROM project\
                     WHERE project.id IN (1,2,3)"
                   )
```

Instead of (1,2,3) I want to pass a variable but cannot figure out how to do that.

I want to do something like:

```
db.session.execute( "SELECT * \
                   FROM project\
                    WHERE project.id IN 
                    (my_array)"
                   )
```

I have tried this but does not work:

```
db.session.execute( "SELECT * \
                         FROM project\
                         WHERE project.id IN 
                          param",
                     {"param":(1,2,3)}
                   )
```

Please help!:)

Answer (score 0):

change your query to this and pass the values as a tuple :

```
db.session.execute("SELECT * FROM project WHERE project.id IN (%s)",(1,2,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option-1:**

```
raw_sql_param = """
SELECT  *
FROM    project
WHERE   project.id IN :project_id
"""

stmt = text(raw_sql_param)
stmt = stmt.bindparams(bindparam("project_id", expanding=True))
res = session.execute(stmt, {"project_id": [1, 2, 3]})
```

**Option-2: (postgresql specific)**

```
raw_sql_param = """
SELECT  *
FROM    project
WHERE   project.id = ANY(:project_id)
"""

stmt = text(raw_sql_param)
res = session.execute(stmt, {"project_id": [1, 2, 3]})
```

*See similar question with more expanded answers:* [How can I bind a list to a parameter in a custom query in sqlalchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190392/how-can-i-bind-a-list-to-a-parameter-in-a-custom-query-in-sqlalchemy)