# Bind a list to a parameter as json array in custom SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I know thanks to this website that it is possible to [bind a list to a custom query parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190392/how-can-i-bind-a-list-to-a-parameter-in-a-custom-query-in-sqlalchemy), however I have only seen it done with an `IN` clause.

What I am trying to do is to pass a list to a MySQL `JSON_ARRAY`, with no success at the moment

My code looks like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy import text
query = text("INSERT into models (name, elements) VALUES (:model_name, :elements)"
session.execute(query, {"model_name": "foo", "elements": ["bar", "baz"]}
```

But it raises `OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')` as I assume that each element of the list is identified as an indidividual column.

I tried to enclose the `:elements` parameters in a `JSON_ARRAY(...)` to no avail.

Is there a way to leverage SQLALchemy's `text` here, or do  I need to go back to building custom strings to pass with something like

```
session.execute(query, {"model_name": "foo", "elements": '", "'.join(["bar", "baz"])}

?
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd serialize your python array to a *string* in JSON format, then you can bind it as a single scalar value.

```
import json
session.execute(query, {"model_name": "foo", "elements": json.dumps(["bar", "baz"])}
```